# Querying on many to many relationship using GROUP BY 'OR' WHERE

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have two table connect with a many-to-many relationship, Articoli and Fornitori in my Laravel application. In articolo_fornitori table there is articolo_id which refers to ID of Articoli and fornitore_id which refers to ID in Fornitori.

| Articoli | Articolo_Fornitori | Fornitori |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | ID | ID |
| descr | articolo_id | rag_soc |
| pos | fornitore_id | sito |
| prezzo | cod_art_for | iva |
| note | preferito | note |

I need to search with one query all the Articoli that have the given fornitore_id as unique Fornitore OR if they have many Fornitore, the given supplier should be preferred (preferito=si).

The model are:

Articoli

```
protected $table = 'articoli';

    protected $fillable = [
        'cod_articolo',
        'descrizione',
        'quantita_minima',
        'note',
        'posizione',
        'prezzo_vendita',
    ];

public function articolo_fornitore()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArticoloFornitore::class);
    }
```

ArticoloFornitore

```
protected $table = 'articolo_fornitore';

protected $fillable = [
        'articolo_id',
        'fornitore_id',
        'cod_articolo_fornitore',
        'quantita_giacente',
        'preferito',
    ];

    public function articolo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Articolo::class, 'articolo_id');
    }

    public function fornitore()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Fornitore::class, 'fornitore_id');
    }
```

Fornitore

```
protected $table = 'fornitori';

protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'rag_sociale',
        'pec',
        'sito',
        'p_iva',
        'cod_fiscale',
        'note',
        'mod_pagamento_id',
    ];

public function articolo_fornitore()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArticoloFornitore::class);
    }
```

I need this query for my Laravel App.

This is the query I wrote in SQL and seems to work.

```
SELECT 
    articoli.id, articoli.cod_articolo 
FROM 
    articoli 
INNER JOIN 
    articolo_fornitore on articoli.id = articolo_fornitore.articolo_id INNER JOIN 
    fornitori ON articolo_fornitore.fornitore_id = fornitori.id 
WHERE 
    (articolo_fornitore.fornitore_id = $idfornitore AND 
     articolo_fornitore.preferito = "si") 
    OR (articolo_fornitore.fornitore_id = $idfornitore 
        AND articoli.id IN (SELECT articoli.id 
                            FROM articoli 
                            INNER JOIN articolo_fornitore ON articoli.id = articolo_fornitore.articolo_id 
                            GROUP BY articoli.id 
                            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT articolo_fornitore.fornitore_id) = 1))
```

Comment: First of all, many many relationships needs to use `belongsToMany` in both models, you can start from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) then you will understand how to get what you need

Comment: I have the _belongsToMany_ methods in both models but i have problem with the update of the pivot table because my pivot table has attribute

Comment: Bro, you can't just ignore the basics and doc and head directly to stackoverflow because you'll face issues as you go, here's how to [insert/update pivot](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: i have already tried this but every time i update pivot table it remove the attributes, but the problem ins't this. I need the know if is possible make a query with WHERE clauses OR the GROUP BY and HAVING in laravel, or how to convert mu sql query in eloquent

Answer (score 1):

This is the query in Eloquent that I made and it seems to work:

```
Articolo::whereHas('articolo_fornitore', function($query) use($fornitore_id) {
                    $query->where('fornitore_id', '=', $fornitore_id)
                          ->where('preferito', '=', 'si')//;})
                          ->orwhere('fornitore_id', '=', $fornitore_id)
                          ->whereIn('articoli.id', function($subquery){
                            $subquery->select('articoli.id')
                            ->from('articoli')
                            ->join('articolo_fornitore', 'articoli.id', '=', 'articolo_id')
                            ->groupBy('articoli.id')
                            ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT fornitore_id) = 1');
                          });
                })
                ->sortable('cod_articolo')
                ->paginate(15);
```